# Why is Vue3 composition API better than just a helper class?

Tags: vuejs3, vue-composition-api

Maybe it's just me, but after diving into the new Vue3 composition API, I don't really see the benifit of it, compared to just creating a new class that exports some helper functions (functions to prevent duplicated code). Can someone please clarify this for me?

Answer (score 1):

official doc actually has a pretty good detailed explanation with examples, you can check step by step starting from here: https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/composition-api-introduction.html#why-composition-api

The most important is:

> Such fragmentation is what makes it difficult to understand and maintain a complex component. The separation of options obscures the underlying logical concerns. In addition, when working on a single logical concern, **we have to constantly "jump" around option blocks for the relevant code**.

Any helper classes can minimize logical concerns fragmentation. So everything is almost next to each other, but still you'll have to separate and put them to different Options api sections (data, watchers, computed, etc)

It can't eliminate mentioned "jumps" around option blocks.

> It would be much nicer if we could collocate code related to the same logical concern. And this is exactly what the Composition API enables us to do.

Comment: True, and I did read the above mentioned article. But one thing that I forgot to mention, is that I am using `vue-class-component` , so I can already organize my data, watchers, computed etc. that have the same functionality and put them below each other as with `vue-class-component` you are not bounded to the API section blocks